# what is cursor object in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I understand the concept of PL/SQL variables but I am unable to get clear picture of cursor objects in PL/SQL in my mind.

I have read the below written text somewhere and and feel myself unable to understand the concept of cursor objects.

> "If the cursor variable has not yet
>   been assigned to any cursor object,
>   the OPEN FOR statement implicitly
>   creates an object for the variable.
>   If at the time of the OPEN the cursor
>   variable already is pointing to a
>   cursor object, then OPEN FOR does not
>   create a new object. Instead, it
>   reuses the existing object and
>   attaches a new query to that object.
>   The cursor object is maintained
>   separately from the cursor or query
>   itself. "

please explain me how it works internally.....

Comment: The above is a quote from Steven Feuerstein's Oracle PL/SQL Programming book: http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514464/

Answer (score 0):

you can regard it as a pointer which is used in C programming language(if you ever have learnt), it points to each row of the data retrieved from the SQL statement. Move the cursor to next line to read the next row.

Ref: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs9311/10s2/lectures/week04/PL_SQL.pdf
this is the lecture notes which I used to learn PL/SQL

Answer (score 0):

To my understand, a cursor is like a pointer that point to a row in a result set.  In other programming language, it is like a enumerator. A enumerator is a object that helps goes though a collection of items.

For example:

```
declare
  cursor cur is select * from someTable;

begin
  open cur;
  loop
    fetch cur into record;
    exit when cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('Col1: ' || record.col1 || ', Col2: ' || record.col2);
  end loop;
end;
```

would be similar to this in C#:

```
    string[] collection = new string[]{"A", "B", "C"};
    var enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();
    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("current item:" + enumerator.Current);
    }
```

Notice that you use the cursor to get record data is similar to use a enumerator to get the data.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks to both of you.. Shang i do understand the concept of pointers in C language. but in C  language a pointer variable conatains the adderess of some memory location on which we perform operations.

Comment: but here the scenario is quite different as cursor variable here points to a cursor object which in turn points to the dataset in SGA.

Comment: so is it like pointer to a pointer or if it is so then what is the need of this why cannot we use just use pointer(cursor variable)